# iOS Swift Remove Paste Option

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I want to remove the option "Paste" from the selector

I've tried the code below but it adds other selections to the selector and the paste option is still there, it just disables the functionality

```
override func canPerformAction(action: Selector, withSender sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    if action == "paste:" {
        return false
    }
    return true
  }
```

I want to remove Paste all together so the user doesn't even have the option to see it or click it

[image]

Comment: Try comparing `action` to `let pasteAction = "paste:" as Selector` or something along those lines.

Comment: That thread explains how to disable the functionality, I want to remove it completely from the selector so my selector only says Select, Select All

Comment: Ohh I see. I misunderstood what you were asking. My apologies!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at UIMenuController
You should be able to use 
var menuItems: [AnyObject]?

to set up your own object.

It is not a simple switch on or off the existing buttons, looks like you have to provide your own.

Comment: is it possible to just hide the UIMenuController completely for the viewcontroller?

Comment: Try 'code' let menu = UIMenuController() ; menu.setMenuVisible(false, animated: false)

Comment: still appears with the code above.  I checked menu.menuItems.count and it returned nil but I still have the selector appearing

Answer (score 0):

try this :

Step 1: You need to create another class which extends the `UITextField`. In this example, I made my `CustomizedUITextField`.

```
import UIKit

class CustomTextField: UITextField {
    override func canPerformAction(action: Selector, withSender sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        if action == "paste:" {
            return false
        }

        return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
    }
}
```